# Dbms sqltune procedure is keeps running

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have executed sql tuning task on a long query with multiple joins.
My tuning task keeps running for hours. 
Individual query takes 21 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `DBMS_SQLTUNE.CREATE_TUNING_TASK`, add a parameter like `time_limit => 600` to set the maximum number of seconds.

But my experience with SQL tuning tasks has been poor.  I've never seen the advisor recommend anything that I couldn't have easily figured out myself.  While you're using that package, generate a SQL monitor report with `DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR`.  That report includes lots of good information, such as estimated and actual values, waits, etc.  You can hopefully use that information to find the cause of your problem.